# improvements in the tour

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, duplicates

I would like to propose in the tour, to point out the importance of searching in the 'Search' for a question before asking it on SE. The questions come up time and again, an asked question or duplicate.
Also the search box  make it more prominent so people will see it better.

Comment: I asked a [relevant question](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/640/first-posts-problems) a while back

Comment: It was the tone of the writers that make me feel uncomfortable. That's why I asked this question. It is sometimes new people to the se, ask questions yes it's off topic , duplicate whatever. They get a barrage off topic, duplicate it chases away people or make them have a  bad taste.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the search box is incredibly obvious, in the same place most sites have it, and in the same format. Also, when you post a question, the system does a pretty good dupe search anyway - but getting someone to accept that it is a dupe is another matter...

Changing it would be a Dev activity, so I can't speak to whether we will get any changes to the tour, however, if it doesn't get changed, there is something you and I can do to help new folks:

- let them know about the search box if they missed it

If this is done in a welcome message, you can let them feel welcomed and educated as to how to ask in future.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I don't like how people comment bordering command to out right nasty. We are still humans.

Comment: generally, most SE sites I frequent have people being polite and friendly. I didn't understand you calling out Neil earlier - he was not being rude. I'm guessing it's the difference between cultures that caused that issue.